# nilpotent uniform pro-$p$ groups of dimension 2

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, profinite-groups, nilpotent-groups, pro-p-groups

I read in a paper that all nilpotent uniform pro-$p$ groups of dimension $\leq 2$ are Abelian (Prime Decomposition and the Iwasawa $\mu$-Invariant by Hajir-Maire, *Math. Proc. of the Camb. Phil. Soc.* (2019) Section 5.1). This is probably obvious, but I am unable to prove this nor have I seen a reference.

This would mean $\mathbb{Z}_p \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is solvable but not nilpotent; what about $\mathbb{Z}_p^d \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ when $d>1$? Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the notation for the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: Can you give relevant definitions? The groups you have at the end are $p$-groups so definitely nilpotent.

Comment: these are pro-$p$ groups (infinite) and hence not *definitely* nilpotent. I agree that finite $p$ groups are always nilpotent.

Comment: Writing a semidirect product doesn't tell you what the group is, if you don't specify the action. Once you specify the action, you should be able to describe the lower central series.

Comment: @debanjana I was assuming that by $\mathbb{Z}_p$, you meant the cyclic group of order $p$, in which case the groups at the end of your post are finite. If you mean something else, please explain.

Comment: Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the notation for the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @verret $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has been used for $p$-adics much before it was used for the cyclic group. In a question about profinite groups, it's hardly a surprise that it's used in this meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal and entries in $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is 2-step nilpotent (and not abelian), and is a semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}_p^2\rtimes\mathbf{Z}_p$.

(The case $d=1$ is special: one can use the fact that every $2$-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra is abelian.)